# value setting for TGridpanel working not as expected

Tags: delphi

I would like to extend the question given here at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838062/delphi-how-to-use-tgridpanel)

I dropped one TGridpanel my form and i would like to set the ratio between first and second row. Target should be 15 % for row #1 and 85 % for row #2.  Open up the value editor and entering eg. 15 in the OI i get values close to the target value (15,2%)  but not the correct ones. What is going wrong ? With other ratio values the error is in the range up to 5 %

**[image: Tgridpanel]**

Comment: I never found a way around this and always press [Alt]+[F12] to edit the DFM syntax of the `TGridPanel` manually, then press [Alt]+[F12] again to switch back to the design view which should now be correct.

Comment: It is odd behaviour. I have found that repeatedly entering the number you want will get there.  Using your example, I entered 15 6 times before it settle at 15 / 85.  @GünthertheBeautiful's idea is good - I'll consider using that when there are more than 2 columns.  As to why it happens, I've no clear idea.

Comment: Delphi was always bad with floats in DFM and sub-pixel accuracy in controls positioning. The basic design was made 20 years ago for 16-bit processors and they squeezed every tick-tock they could. Today VCL is badly hurt by it with different DPI on modern screens...

Comment: @Arioch'The, Well, the behaviour is exactly the same on FireMonkey. I'm sure there is some kind of logic. Set both columns to zero percent, and both get exactly 50%. Now set the first one to 100%, it becomes 66,66%. Probably because that's 100/(100+50)

Comment: "*What is going on?*" The accepted answer to the question you linked to, explains exactly what is going on. Sorry, but this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delphi How to use TGridPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838062/delphi-how-to-use-tgridpanel)

Comment: For what I remember exactly tendency of FMX to use floats highlighted problems of DFM engine in saving it. Maybe it was fixed with newer Delphi releases, dunno